# How to compute absolute Dtype value in Caffe?

Tags: c++, caffe

I'm working on creating a custom layer in Caffe. I need to compute an absolute value of Dtype for a few elements (not the whole blob). Which absolution function should I use?

```
const Dtype* prob_data = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
const Dtype* label = bottom[1]->cpu_data();
...
const int idx = ...
Dtype A = Dtype(-20); // example
Dtype B = Dtype(10);  // example
...
Dtype myval = fabs(A+B+prob_data[idx]); // which abs function to be used here??
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer for my solution after looking through the caffe code.
I could simply do

```
Dtype myval = Dtype( std::abs(A+B+prob_data[idx]) );
```